# How do you hide Socket.io error messages in C++?

Tags: socket.io

So I get error messages like this printed to the console from Socket.io:

```
[2023-02-09 17:53:43] [info] asio async_resolve error: asio.system:11001 (No such host is known.)
[2023-02-09 17:53:43] [info] Error getting remote endpoint: asio.system:10009 (The file handle supplied is not valid.)
[2023-02-09 17:53:43] [error] handle_connect error: No such host is known.
[2023-02-09 17:53:43] [info] asio async_shutdown error: asio.ssl:336462100 (uninitialized)
```

I just need to hide them from the console but cannot figure out how to do it. I've tried using `off_error`, set logs quiet, and try/catch but none worked.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Please show a minimal self-contained example. I removed the c++ tag for now, because nothing about the question is remotely related to c++